# What is the Merovingian referring to by "C*ck-me-climatey-Wiki-piss-and-sh*t"?

Tags: the-matrix-resurrections

In *The Matrix Resurrections* (2021), Neo and company were confronted by Smith, the Merovingian, and other exile programs. As they engaged in combat, the Merovingian ranted about the current state of the Matrix, blaming the changes on Neo. Quoting the Merovingian (emphasis mine):

> You ruined every suck-my-silky-ass thing!
> We had grace.
> ...
> We had style! We had conversation!
> Not this... [mimics text message sound]
> ...
> Art, films, books were all better! Originality mattered!
> **You gave us** Face-Zucker-suck and **Cock-me-climatey-Wiki-piss-and-shit!**

I understand that "Face-Zucker-suck" is a reference to Facebook and Facebook CEO, Mark Zuckerberg, and probably social media in general, but I'm not sure what the Merovingian was referring to by "Cock-me-climatey-Wiki-piss-and-shit". I'm thinking it might be Wikipedia or wiki-based systems in general, but I'm not sure how they connect to "Cock-me-climatey" and why the Merovingian hates wiki-based systems.

Note: "Cock-me-climatey-Wiki-piss-and-shit" is the text from the subtitles. The "Cock-me-climatey" part is unintelligible to me, so I'm not sure if the subtitles are correct. As commented below, it sounds like "couch-flicks-climatey."

Comment: Maybe a reference to f***ed up climate change.

Comment: I hear "couch flicks", and with him ranting about "art, films, books", mentioning Netflix/streaming would make sense.

Comment: @Oliver_C Upon rewatching, I seem to hear "couch flicks" too. I've edited the question to include this info.

Answer (score 1):

As the analyst says, the new matrix is about controlling feelings.

> Ooh! Nicely done. You ever wonder why you have nightmares? Why your own brain tortures you? It’s actually us, maximizing your output. It works just like this. Oh, no! Can you stop the bullet? If only you could move faster. [chuckles] Here’s the thing about feelings. They’re so much easier to control than facts. Turns out, in my Matrix, the worse we treat you, the more we manipulate you, the more energy you produce. It’s nuts. [chomps] I’ve been setting productivity records every year since I took over. And, the best part, zero resistance. People stay in their pods, happier than pigs in shit. The key to it all? You. And her. Quietly yearning for what you don’t have, while dreading losing what you do. For 99.9% of your race, that is the definition of reality. Desire and fear, baby. Just give the people what they want, right?

Facebook is an online record of what all your friends are doing that helps you yearn for what others have, and fear stepping out of line and losing what you have. Desire and fear.

Wikipedia is an easily alterable repository of facts that people look at to learn what they should desire or fear. You can learn quickly what a political ideology is like, or how hackers are evil people who you shouldn't trust. If someone desires the wrong thing, a quick edit to wiki lets the machines set them on track.

Climate change is a constant fear of people that encourages changes and forces you to fear losing it all. The real Matrix climate is fucked up with the sun being blocked, but in the virtual world the fear of climate change lets the matrix make you fear losing everything you desire.

They later discuss climate change. The analyst says this.

> You think you hold all the cards, because you can do whatever you want in this world. I say, go for it. Remake it. Knock yourselves out. Paint the sky with rainbows. But here’s the thing. The sheeple aren’t going anywhere. They like my world.

Neo and Trinity respond.

> We’re not here to negotiate anything. We were on our way to remake your world. Change a few things. **I kind of like the “paint the sky with rainbows” idea.** Just remind people what a free mind can do.

Since the Matrix is a virtual world, they can freely alter the weather with the power of their minds. They can break the Analyst's control by altering, among other things, the climate.